# Why does FormValidator::Simple prefer array to hash?

Tags: perl

Quoted from [here](http://http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?FormValidator%3a%3aSimple#SYNOPSIS):

```
my $result = FormValidator::Simple->check( $query => [
    param1 => ['NOT_BLANK', 'ASCII', ['LENGTH', 2, 5]],
    param2 => ['NOT_BLANK', 'INT'  ],
    mail1  => ['NOT_BLANK', 'EMAIL_LOOSE'],
    mail2  => ['NOT_BLANK', 'EMAIL_LOOSE'],
    { mails => ['mail1', 'mail2'       ] } => ['DUPLICATION'],
    { date  => ['year',  'month', 'day'] } => ['DATE'],
] );
```

IMO it should be :

```
my $result = FormValidator::Simple->check( $query => {
    ...
} );
```

Why does [FormValidator::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?FormValidator%3a%3aSimple) prefer array to hash?

Comment: I can't picture something that would work with a hash. What do you think it would look like? Fill in the `...`, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you suggesting you should be able to use

```
my $result = FormValidator::Simple->check( $query => {
    param1 => ['NOT_BLANK', 'ASCII', ['LENGTH', 2, 5]],
    param2 => ['NOT_BLANK', 'INT'  ],
    mail1  => ['NOT_BLANK', 'EMAIL_LOOSE'],
    mail2  => ['NOT_BLANK', 'EMAIL_LOOSE'],
    { mails => ['mail1', 'mail2'       ] } => ['DUPLICATION'],
    { date  => ['year',  'month', 'day'] } => ['DATE'],
} );
```

That would pass the following

```
{
    param1 => ['NOT_BLANK', 'ASCII', ['LENGTH', 2, 5]],
    param2 => ['NOT_BLANK', 'INT'  ],
    mail1  => ['NOT_BLANK', 'EMAIL_LOOSE'],
    mail2  => ['NOT_BLANK', 'EMAIL_LOOSE'],
    'HASH(0x2aaffc)' => ['DUPLICATION'],
    'HASH(0x32aff4)' => ['DATE'],
}
```

There's lots of information missing.